# Serialize FontFamily in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone, xml-serialization, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to read/save a xml-file in my windows phone application with the XmlSerializer. Unfortunately I can't read/write it because I'm using the FontFamily in my class:

```
public class Article
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    private FontFamily _fontitem;
    public FontFamily FontItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _fontitem;
        }
        set
        {
            _fontitem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => FontItem);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a class named StorageHelper just like here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dawate/archive/2010/08/31/windows-phone-7-xml-isolatedstorage-example.aspx
Instead of the class "Jog" I use my class "Article".

When I try to load/save the xml this error comes up: "*fontfamily cannot be serialized because it does not have a paramterless constructor*"

Comment: Do you really need the `FontFamily` to be serialized? If not you can put `XmlIgnore` attribute on `FontItem` property and it won't be serialized, and therefore won't throw an exception

Comment: @AndroidJoker It's not necessary in the Article-class, but I've got a Config-Class where everything is saved (it has also a property with fontfamily) and I'd do the same approach there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can create a `FontFamily` from its name. Therefore you can modify your `Article` class to be like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Article
{
    private string _fontItemString;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public FontFamily FontItem
    {
        get
        {
            return new FontFamily(FontItemString);
        }
    }

    public string FontItemString
    {
        get { return _fontItemString; }
        set
        {
            _fontItemString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => FontItem);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't serialize the `FontFamily` object itself, but serialize the name of the font family to use. Whenever the font family string changes, you can notify the actual `FontItem` was changed, and then initialize the `FontFamily` from `FontItemString`